# Issues trying yo add a controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was trying to add a controller to my project and its coming on with this popup.
unable to retrive metadata for 'MVCMovie.Models.MOvie'. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio completely and then reopen your solution.